# Why does the website is getting lost after visiting to any link and refreshing

Tags: angular, web, hosting, web-hosting

I've created this website using Angular. After visiting to any link and refreshing in that particular link. Website is showing the same error that is shown in the attached SS.
Please visit this website for more clarification of the problem and help me solve the problem

https://dungeshwari.com

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that you have a 404 error when refreshing your application since the actual address within the browser is updating. When you start from `/home` or `/` your single page application navigates user internally between pages. So when you refresh on `/homepage` you will see 404 - you see nothing, because your component `HomepageComponent` html file is not served on `https://dungeshwari.com/homepage`.

You need to setup routing https://angular.io/guide/router

e.g

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more way to solve this issue
first way :- You have to add in your root module file

`imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]`

Second way is that

```
import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router'; 
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router'; 
import {MyApp} from './myapp';

bootstrap(MyApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```